# Iterate in a list and store values in dynamic variables

Tags: python, list

I have a list like this
`list = ["mkhg" , "ghkl" , "hjyu" , "jkkp"]` I want to iterate through this list and store the values in dynamic variables. Say for example, `"mkhg"` is stored in variable `a` , `"ghkl"` is stored in variable `c` and so on. Is there a way to crack this?

Comment: `a,b,c,d = *list`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create a variable number of variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables)

Comment: What do you mean by "dynamic variable"?  Do you mean the _name_ of the variable isn't known beforehand?

Comment: @John Gordon yes something like that

Comment: Why do you need dynamic variables? Could you use a `dict` or `list`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
list = ["mkhg" , "ghkl" , "hjyu" , "jkkp"]
```

Variable name shadows the bultin `list` type, don't do that.

You can achieve this with `exec` but it's a really dirty hack, so it's more of a fun fact rather than useful pattern:

```
l = ["mkhg" , "ghkl" , "hjyu" , "jkkp"]
variable_names = ["a","b","c","d"]

for name, value in zip(variable_names, l):
    exec(f"{name}=value")
print(a) # mkhg
```

Most times you'll be better of with a dict:

```
values = {"a": "mkhg", "b": "ghkl"}
# or dynamically created

values = dict(zip(variable_names, l))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! A quick question - is there a way to achieve this without declaring the variable names beforehand?

Comment: Yeah, variable names can be generated as you like, but in the end you'll need a list of strings.